# When using jQueryUI "toggle", why does div open and immediately close  in internet explorer 8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, jquery

i have the following code, where ToggleFilter is a button.  The button click with EITHER opens or close the div - depending on previous state (based on vis attr).

```
$("#toggleFilter").click(function (e) {

    var vis = $(this).attr('vis');
    if (vis == '0') {
        $(this).attr('vis', '1');
        $("#toggleFilter").button("option", "icons", { primary: 'ui-icon-search', secondary: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-s' });
    }
    else {
        $(this).attr('vis', '0');
        $("#toggleFilter").button("option", "icons", { primary: 'ui-icon-search', secondary: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-e' });
    }
    var options = {};
    $("#accordion").toggle('blind', options, 500);
});
```

anyway, this works fine in Firefox, Chrome, IE7 but in IE8, when i click the button, the accordian opens up and immediately closes.  I put an alert() in the code and the click event is only firing once so i can't figure out what is causing the div to show but immediately close on Internet Explorer 8.

has anyone seen this weird behavior in IE8 and has a suggestion?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

still don't fully understand why but upgrading from jquery 1.4.2 to 1.4.4 seems to have fixed the issue.